# Visual Studio Autocomplete Too Aggressive With Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, unity-game-engine

I use visual studio with Unity. The autocomplete function that visual studio has built in, in conjunction with Tools for Unity, makes the autocomplete, especially with method headers, way too aggressive.

For instance, when I type `void OnCollisionEnter(` I am given

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) { }()
```

This is a problem because I now have to remove the parenthesis and rename the parameter, when before I would not have to do either. It's a small thing, but it is extremely aggravating. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I uninstalled the Tools for Unity and I now know that it was causing the problem. However, now I don't have autocomplete functions for any part of unity. Is there a way to do it without uninstalling tools for unity?

Comment: Yup, this is indeed an issue, although I have yet to determine the root cause. On version 2.8.0.0 btw, don't know if that matters.

Comment: And for the lovers of jiffs https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Pe5.gif

Comment: To fix the addition of the private key word (all of my code says either void or public void, so it is both silly and confusing to add private), I found that you can change the Unity Messages scope to default within the tools for unity settings in Tools -> Options -> Tools For Unity

Comment: I just encountered the-same problem after re-installing VS and the VSTU plugin. It's indeed annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VS Tools for Unity (VSTU) provide completion for Unity Messages (special methods that are called from the Unity engine, such as OnCollisionEnter).

Good news, the issue you describe is an issue that we have identified and that we're working on fixing. If it's *extremely aggravating*, in the meantime, you can either:

1. Keep the Tools for Unity installed, and disable that particular feature in Tools -> Options -> Tools for Unity, and set Unity Message code completion to False. You might have to re-open the project for it to take effect.
2. Commit the method snippet by using enter or tab when the IntelliSense shows the Unity Message you want to add, even if it goes against your muscle memory for a while :)

Disclaimer: I'm the Dev Lead for the Tools for Unity at Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks! Its not aggravating to the point of needing to remove it, but I hadn't noticed it before. I'm glad you guys are working on it! VS is still much better than monodevelop. Also, it is really impressive that you guys detected this issue and are dedicated to fixing it.